# Connection between any sources and google-cloud-Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm new to Google cloud platform. I want to know how to connect my client sources data in order that they arrive in the pub/sub system?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really general question, some more specific information from your side could be useful to answer in more detail.

You can start by reading up on some resources:

1. [What is Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/): gives you a very high-level overview of what Pub/Sub is and does.
2. [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console): helps you on some of the concepts and gets you started using Pub/Sub
3. More detailed info for actually publishing data to Pub/Sub using the [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/apis) or one of the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) can be found in these resources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to know if I have many devices accross the world and I want them to send messages to my pu/sub system. I know i should specify the topic name but what I don't know is that how does the data arrive from my devices to the pub/sub.

Comment: Well, these devices will need to publish the messages to Pub/Sub, using API requests or an application developed using one of the client libraries as specified in 3. above. Pub/Sub will not discover these devices for you, but will gather messages that are published by your devices and aggregate them in a topic. You might want to look into [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) to actually process messages received from your devices.

Comment: OK, now I understand. So that, the API request or client library allows the connection between pub/sub and the other side sources. Thank you very much

Comment: Note that sending messages from a bunch of devices, e.g., phones or IoT devices, directly into Pub/Sub is likely not what you want to do. See [my response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733481/can-someone-explain-the-difference-between-gcm-and-google-pub-sub/37734582#37734582) for some more details. Depending on the nature of your devices, [Cloud IoT Core](https://cloud.google.com/iot-core/) might be the way to get messages into Pub/Sub.

Comment: So in the case of Cloud IoT core, still I use the client libraries? And if it is data from a wibsite that I want to come to my pub/sub, how do I have to do it? Sorry for too many questions, I'm very new to this plateforme but I want to understand the concept!